# malloc: *** error for object 0x1001002e0: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++

please
help me I am running the code of api microtik, but I have this error

```
 malloc: *** error for object 0x1001002e0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

any body could help me?

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint on `malloc_error_break` and debug it?

Comment: If this really is c++ you probably shouldn't be allocating memory like that.

Comment: @Carl Norum Where'd you get that idea?

Comment: Voting to close as rhetorical.

Comment: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/40661-set-breakpoint-malloc_error_break-debug.html

Comment: If this is iphone wouldn't it be obj-C instead of C++?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break and debug the application.